# seaborn matplotlib wrapping of x axis not working

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I'm trying to wrap my x axis like so, but it still overlaps. I dont know what's happening. Not sure if I have to adjust the space for the x axis height... but if i do i dont know how to do it. Can you please point me to the right direction. Thanks

```
       import pandas as pd
        from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
        import matplotlib as mpl
        import seaborn as sns
        import textwrap

            myvalues= {
                'my_labels': [ 'Title one' ,'Title two extend' ,'Title three extend' ,'Title four extend' ,'Title five extend' ,'Title six extend' ,'Title seven extend'],
                'val_1': [1,1,1,1,1,6,7],
                'val_2': [3,6,3,5,7,1,9],
                'val_3' : [5,5,2,4,4,5,4]
            }

            data = pd.DataFrame(myvalues, columns=['my_labels', 'val_1', 'val_2', 'val_3' ])

            sns.set_context({"figure.figsize": (18, 10)})
            ax=sns.barplot(x = data.my_labels, y = data.val_1, color = "#001a7b")
            ax.set_xticklabels(['\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(ticklabel.get_text(),9)) for ticklabel in ax.get_xticklabels()])
            ax.set(ylim=(0,3))
#edit:    
    axis2 = plt.twinx()
    axis2.set(ylim=(0, 16))
    axis2.grid(False)

    line_1 = sns.lineplot(x = data.my_labels, y = data.val_1, color = "#E4521B", lineWidth=3, marker="o", ax=axis2, sort=False)
```

EDIT:
Updated code with a line on top of the bars. When I remove it the labels get wrapped, otherwise it goes back to one line

Answer (score 0):

In the line

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(t.get_text(),9)) for x in ax.get_xticklabels()])
# why two different variables?              ^                    ^
#                                           |                    |
```

you iterate through the labels as x, but then you call the method `get_text()` of a variable called `t`. You should write

```
ax.set_xticklabels(['\n'.join(textwrap.wrap(ticklabel.get_text(),9)) for ticklabel in ax.get_xticklabels()])
```

**EDIT**

In response to your newly modified question, the call to `lineplot()` overwrites the label that you had set previously. To overcome this problem, simply move the line `ax.set_xticklabels(...)` *after* `sns.lineplot()`

Comment: Ah! Thank you, such a silly typo. I got it updated, and it works perfectly on the current code, what I forgot to mention was there's another plot of it that's preventing the wrap to happen. I update the code above. You can run but the wrapping doesn't happen.

Comment: @gdubs I've edited my answer, you simply have to move the line `ax.set_xticklabels(...)` at the end of your script